# OpenCV stereoRectify distorts image

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

we have a ELP 1.0 Megapixel Dual Lens Usb Stereo camera and we are trying to calibrate it using OpenCV 3.1 in C++. However, the result of the calibration is totally unusable, because calling stereoRectify totally twistes the image. This is what we do:

Finding calibration (chessboard) pattern in both cameras, chessboard size is 5x7 and the result is almost same regardless the number of images taken

```
findChessboardCorners(img[k], boardSize, corners, CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
cornerSubPix(img[k], corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT+TermCriteria::EPS, 30, 0.01));
```

All chessboards are correctly detected that is verified using

```
drawChessboardCorners(img[k], boardSize, corners, bFound);
```

Then we calibrate each camera separately (but this step seems not to be important for stereo calibration), but we can use it to verify each camera separately

```
calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints[k], Size(320, 240), cameraMatrix[k], distCoeffs[k], rvecs, tvecs, 0)
```

Then we do stereo calibration

```
stereoCalibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints[0], imagePoints[1], cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0], cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1],
    Size(320, 240), R, T, E, F, CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS);
```

Compute the rectification transform

```
stereoRectify(cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0], cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1], Size(320, 240), R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q,
    CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, 1, Size(320, 240), &validRoI[0], &validRoI[1]);
```

Initialize maps for remap

```
Mat rmap[2][2];
initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0], R1, P1, Size(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT), CV_16SC2, rmap[0][0], rmap[0][1]);
initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1], R2, P2, Size(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT), CV_16SC2, rmap[1][0], rmap[1][1]);
...
remap(img, rimg, rmap[k][0], rmap[k][1], INTER_LINEAR);
imshow("Canvas", rimg);
```

The result is totally distorted image. As I said at the beginning, all calibration/chessboard patterns are correctly detected and if we don't call stereoRectify function, the undistorted images (after remap) look perfect. The problem comes if we call stereoRectify function.

Is there something we missed out?
The number of calibration images does not seem to have any effect (sometimes taking 2 images provides better result (but still not usable) than 10 images)

This is the example of calibration pattern. We take several different orientations:

[image]

This is the result of the calibration if we do not call stereoRectify:
[image]

This is the wrong result if we call stereoRectify (but mostly it gets much worse):
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help what could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey have you tried changing the value of parameter alpha in function stereoRectify. I remember that once I also obtained such results and changing the value of alpha to 0 did the work for me.
Please let me know the results you obtain with alpha = -1, alpha=0.5 and alpha =0

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It helped a lot, but I noticed the following:
- at least CALIB_FIX_K3 needs to be passed into CalibrateCamera and CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH info stereoCalibrate else the result is totally messed
- I get RMS around 0.1 from calibrateCamera but very high RMS around 20 from stereoCalibrate
- although the result looks good now, the image seems to be zoomed a bit after remap
- I have 320x240, if I manually resize image to 640x480 before chessboard detection and then scale the result down by 2.0, the result seems to be perfect

Comment: You can  control the zoom level of image with parameter alpha and do you got the extrinsics of the camera correct ? Because in my case translation vector was off by 3-4 cm. Though it's not relevant but I would add that I got better results with  CalTech ToolBox for Matlab .

Comment: Alpha parameter really affects the zoom level. However, anything different from alpha=0 waves the image edges and surrounds it with black areas (it's understandable), but the finest result (=no distortion, no twisting etc.) I get is with alpha=0 and upscaling the chessboard image before findChessboardCorners and then downscaling the detected corners.

Comment: ok, we just did a calibration with 70 images. CalibrateCamera returned RMS around 0.13 but stereoCalibrate still returned high RMS around 14. I removed those image which gave high epipolar error and now RMS is around 0.2 and this seems to be very good. However, disparity map is much worse for calibrated images - even far objects are marked as very close.

Comment: Did you try calculating the Depth from the disparity map and check the difference?

Comment: We performed new calibration with the chessboard in several distances and the result is very good! Depth is computed using Q matrix returned from stereoRectify as: ((1/Q[3][2]) * Q[2][3]) / disparity)

Answer (score 8):

Just to sumarize if someone needs similar help, this is what I do to get the best lookable result:

Upscale the chessboard image before corner detection:

```
Mat resized;
resize(img[k], resized, Size(FRAME_WIDTH * 2, FRAME_HEIGHT * 2), 0.0, 0.0, INTER_LINEAR);
 findChessboardCorners(resized, boardSize, corners, CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE
```

Downscale the detected corners:

```
for (int i = 0; i < corners.size(); ++i) {
    corners[i].x /= 2.0;
    corners[i].y /= 2.0;
}
```

Calibrate each camera separately:

```
double rms = calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints[k], Size(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT), cameraMatrix[k], distCoeffs[k], rvecs, tvecs,
    CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT | CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO | CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST | CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL | CALIB_FIX_K3 | CALIB_FIX_K4 | CALIB_FIX_K5);
```

Calibrate stereo camera:

```
stereoCalibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints[0], imagePoints[1], cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0], cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1],
    Size(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT), R, T, E, F, 
    CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC | CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH,
    TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT + TermCriteria::EPS, 30, 0));
```

Compute rectification (with alpha = 0.0):

```
stereoRectify(cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0], cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1], Size(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT), 
    R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q,
    CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, 0.0, Size(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT), &validRoI[0], &validRoI[1]);
```

These are the calibration result matrices

Intrinsics:

```
M1: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 2.6187262304487734e+02, 0., 1.5950000000000000e+02, 0.,
       2.6187262304487734e+02, 1.1950000000000000e+02, 0., 0., 1. ]
D1: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 1
   cols: 5
   dt: d
   data: [ -4.6768074176991381e-01, 2.0221327568191746e-01, 0., 0., 0. ]
M2: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 2.6400975025525213e+02, 0., 1.5950000000000000e+02, 0.,
       2.6400975025525213e+02, 1.1950000000000000e+02, 0., 0., 1. ]
D2: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 1
   cols: 5
   dt: d
   data: [ -4.5713211677198845e-01, 2.8855737500717565e-01, 0., 0., 0. ]
```

Extrinsics:

```
R: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 9.9963073433190641e-01, 4.6310793035473068e-04,
       2.7169477545556639e-02, -6.9475632716349024e-04,
       9.9996348636555088e-01, 8.5172324905818230e-03,
       -2.7164541091274301e-02, -8.5329635354663789e-03,
       9.9959455592785362e-01 ]
T: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 1
   dt: d
   data: [ -6.1830090720273198e+01, 1.6774590574449604e+00,
       1.8118983433925613e+00 ]
```

[image]

My another question is whether there are any special requests for variable initializations or is this enough?

```
Mat cameraMatrix[2] = { Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F), Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F) };
Mat distCoeffs[2], R, T, E, F, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q;
```

Comment: I think you should post a new question .