# Reconstructing Stereo images

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have two stereo imgs source nd reference. I have found the fundamental matrix and now i have to reconstruct the ref img(geometrically similar) with corresponding point in src img searching along the epipolar line of that point in ref img.like i have to extract a patch for a point in ref img and compare this patch to the patches in the other image along the epipolar line.I shud pick the patch along the epipolar line which is the best match and place it at the x location of the pt. in this manner i get the reconstructed img. can u tell me how do i pick best match for a patch. like what is the criteria and how do i select the patch size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting the best patch size is a hyperparameter that you choose on your own and that is based on experimentation.  However, choosing the best match along the epipolar line is exactly the same as if you were doing disparity matching.  Simply find the patch along the line that has the smallest sum of squared differences from the reference patch.

However, to make things easier, the epipolar lines are used for stereo *rectification* where scan lines to search for the corresponding patch are done so that the search for patches is done horizontally.  Using `cv2.stereoRectify` combined with `cv2.remap` should help you do this.  Have a look at [OpenCV stereoRectify distorts image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852273/opencv-stereorectify-distorts-image) for inspiration.